# Is there a procedure to locally linearize nonlinear operators from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, jacobian, linearization

If I have a nonlinear operator $T: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\| T(x) \| = \| x \|$ for each $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$, is there a procedure to locally approximate it with a linear orthogonal operator $A : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ inside the neighborhood of a certain vector $x$, for each vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes, you find it derivative (which is a linear operator)

Comment: *"...inside the neighborhood of a certain vector $x$, for each vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$"* is a bit contradictory.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, that would be true if $\|T(x)-T(y)\|=\|x-y\|$, but not in this case

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You are right it wasn’t clear .I mean for every vector x in R^n you take a neighborhood of that vector and you consider the local linear approximation of the operator acting on vectors inside it .

Comment: @PianoPianoaTrattiForte Please update your question and provide such clarification.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you ,I didn’t know about the jacobian matrix .is it necessarily orthogonal given those conditions?(norm preserving for every vector )

Comment: @PianoPianoaTrattiForte I don't think so.

Comment: @PianoPianoaTrattiForte If you keep ignoring the comments and don't improve your question, it will be closed, and not by me.

Answer (score 2):

The object that does this kind of approximation is the gradient of $T$ (the precise name is probably “Jacobian” since we are working with vector-valued functions). More precisely, if you want to approximate $T$ around some vector $x_0$, then
$$ T(x)\approx T(x_0)+\nabla T(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0). $$

In your hypothesis, though, the gradient might not be orthogonal. Think about it in this way: if you only impose $\|T(x)\|=\|x\|$, this means that your operator $T$ acts on the spherical surfaces in $\mathbb R^n$ centered at $0$ with fixed radius, and preserves all these surfaces. But then, the way $T$ acts on such spheres is essentially arbitrary. But locally, these spherical surfaces look like $\mathbb R^{n-1}$… This means that the linear approximation of $T$ restricted to such spheres is essentially an arbitrary linear operator, thus not orthogonal on $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. This suggests that the full approximation of $T$ is not in general orthogonal (if an operator is orthogonal, it must also be an orthogonal operator on all the linear subspaces of the space it acts on).

**Edit.**

If you want another bit of intuition: orthogonal linear maps preserve angles between lines, thus a map that is approximated by a linear orthogonal map at a point $x$ should somehow preserve the angles between curves that pass through $x$ (this is true an can in fact be made rigorous). If you think for some time, maybe you can think of a counterexample of this in the hypotheses you assumed (say, in $\mathbb R^2$).

Small remark: of course, I am assuming the norm you are using is the Euclidean norm, so that the level sets of the norm are spherical surfaces.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun , thanks. I just thought there is one part of the question that is not trivial (the orthogonality of the gradient), even though the OP doesn’t maybe know what the gradient is. However, I will be more careful.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer .the problem is that I know how to compute the gradient for a scalar function f :R^n ->R but I don’t know how to do the same for an operator that maps vectors in R^n to vectors in R^n. Do you mean that I have to apply your reasoning to the Jacobian ?

Comment: Yes. The Jacobian (I called it gradient in my answer because I was thinking of it as an abstract object) is the object you have to look at. Look at the wikipedia page maybe to begin with. Concerning the orthogonality, in your setting you do not have in general that the gradient is orthogonal at a point $x$, and the reason is essentially what I wrote in my answer (even if it’s maybe a bit long to explicitly write down a counterexample).

Comment: @LorenzoPompili You have written more in the comment section than in the answer itself. How is this desirable?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo , being arrogant concerning the work of others on this website does not help building a good environment much more than people overcommenting their own posts. You are free to disagree, but if you want to talk to me please change tune. By the way, you are right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I don't see any arrogance.  You used non-standard terminology and I warned you about it.  You chose to include too much information in the comment section and I warned you about it.  Comments are ephemeral.  If a moderator under the weather deletes them, you are not notified.  Hence, move all relevant information from the comment section to the question itself to protect your work.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thank you ,I thought about it and now I think I understand your answer.I posted another question related to this problem, if you like to I would like to  know your opinion about it, thanks again for your time.